# Angular Prerendering: Using JS conditionally causes 'document is not defined'

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, prerender, angular-ssr

I'm using Angular 15 and I'm trying to pre-render a website for SEO purposes. I understand that facilities such as `document` and `window` aren't available when pre-rendering because the code isn't running on a browser.

I'm using a few JS libraries that manipulate the DOM directly and in order to support pre-rendering I'm doing this:

```js
import Typed from 'typed.js';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  
  typed?: Typed;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.typed = new Typed('#searchdomain', {
          strings: ["example", "anoter" ""],
          typeSpeed: 80,
          contentType: "text"
        });
    }   
  }
```

As you can see `Typed` is only instantiated if the application is running on a browser.

Now I **tried to do the same with Bootstrap 5** however it fails.

```js
import * as Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js';

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  
  private bsModalInstance?: Bootstrap.Modal;
  @ViewChild('bsmodal', {read: ElementRef, static: false}) modalRef?: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
       this.bsModalInstance = new Bootstrap.Modal(this.modalRef?.nativeElement);
     }  
  }
```

Output of `npm run prerender`:

```
⠴ Prerendering 2 route(s) to -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\browser...
Unhandled Promise rejection: document is not defined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at enableDismissTrigger (-path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3878580)
    at -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3879522
    at -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3977330
    at Object.<anonymous> (-path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3977562)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18) ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at enableDismissTrigger (-path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3878580)
    at -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3879522
    at -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3977330
    at Object.<anonymous> (-path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\server\main.js:1:3977562)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
✖ Prerendering routes to -path-\-proj-\dist\-proj-\browser failed.
document is not defined
```

Why does it fail when Bootstraps's `Bootstrap.Modal` isn't even instantiated?

Is there any way to have more debug so I can find the exact file where `document.` is called?

**Update:** I decided to add a `console.log()` on the component's constructor and it never shows up. I believe bootstrap, when imported, is accessing the `document` right away, even before the `Bootstrap.Modal` call.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a problem caused by Bootstrap accessing the `windows`, `document` and some other objects when imported. This was already under discussion at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/34989 with a PR that fixed some of the issues but not all.

I decided to fork the repository and add further fixes to the `jo-ssr-friendly` branch. Also rebased it to the latest stable release.

If anyone comes across this in the future all those fixes can be installed directly from my fork:

```
npm install "https://github.com/TCB13/bootstrap.git#jo-ssr-friendly" --save
```